# Magento 2 how to skip shipping address and shipping methods step

Tags: magento2.2.2, checkout-page, skin

I am trying to skip Shipping address & shipping methods step (i am trying to show checkout page as like downloadable product )

I commented below code in `checkou_index_index.xml` file, but payment step also not displaying

```
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
</item>
```

Comment: have you done this? I am having the same requirement. Can yuo please help me?